# Спряжение глаголов

Tags: спряжение

сменит и сменяет - почему слова относятся к разным спряжениям?

Answer (score 2):

В основе инфинитив "сменить" и "сменять". В первом случае характерный признак второго спряжения - "ИТЬ" в глагольном суффиксе. Во втором случае - "ЯТЬ", такие глаголы относят к первому спряжению.

*Не знаю, что еще тут можно добавить. Или вопрос в том, **почему** так получилось? Тогда этот вопрос слишком глубок для корректного ответа. Как и почти все вопросы на "почему" в лингвистике. Наверное потому, что так язык устроен. )))

Это данность, с которой приходится считаться.*

Answer (score 1):

Почему относятся к разным спряжениям - такая принята классификация по внешним признакам изменения при спряжении. Почему в языке такое различие заложено в глаголы - в данном случае, чтобы при спряжении сохранялось различие между совпадающими по основе глаголами совершенного (сменить) и несовершенного (сменять) вида. Это различие проясняет их функцию. Например: сменила - сменяла (бельё вчера - каждый день прошлого месяца),
сменит - будет сменять (один раз это сделает - будет делать систематически), и т.д.